# How to rotate a TikZ text node depending on its content?

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating

I would like to rotate a TikZ text node by a degree that depends on the content length. So a text node with 20 characters should be rotated e.g. 20*0.1 = 2 degree, a text node with 100 characters for 100*0.1 = 10 degree. It does not matter if whitespace influences this or not.

Is it possible to do that somehow automatically, or do I need to count letters manually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an approximation. First, calculate the average character width, then create a new command to add the node with the rotation set to `<length of node text>/<average character length> * 0.1`.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfmathsetmacro\characterlength{width("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz")/26}
\newcommand{\rotatenode}[3][]{\node [rotate=width("{#3}")/\characterlength*0.1,#1] at (#2) {#3};}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\rotatenode[draw]{0,1}{abcdefghijklmnopqsrt}
\rotatenode[draw,red]{0,2}{abcdefghijklmnopqsrtabcdefghijklmnopqsrtabcdefghijklmnopqsrtabcdefghijklmnopqsrtabcdefghijklmnopqsrt}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: More than good enough approximation for my case, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With lualatex, a little lua code will do.

```latex
%!TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\rnode{O{(0,0)} o m}
{
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}
    {\node at #1 [rotate=\directlua{tex.sprint(string.len("#3"))}] {#3};}
    {\node at #1 [rotate=\directlua{tex.sprint(string.len("#3"))}, #2] {#3};}
    
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \rnode{hello world!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!}
    \rnode[(5,5)][draw, fill=gray!30]{哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]